# Logistic regression not generalizing

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, gradient-descent

According to Andrew Ng's lecture on logictic regression on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/0hpMl/simplified-cost-function-and-gradient-descent) the following cost function can be minimized using the update expression below:

[image]

Running that update function several hundred times on ~150 samples, I get the following pattern, though the cost seems to be decreasing after each iteration as expected:

[image]

The circles are the samples I'm training on, where the input features are the (x, y) coordinate of each point, and the color is the target label. The red or yellow background is what the model predicts that (x, y) input classifies as (red = 0, yellow = 1).

### Question

- Is that update routine not the correct partial derivative of that corresponding cost function J?
- What can this output pattern be an indication of?

---

### Training method

```
// A single pass/epoch

const lr = 0.003;
let params = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];

const scores = samples.map(sample => sig(sum(sample, params));
const errors = scores.map((score, i) => score - labels[i][0]);

params = params.map((param, col) => {
  return param - lr * errors.reduce((acc, error, row) => {
    return acc + error * samples[row][col];
  }, 0);
});
```

### Sample training data

```
const samples = [
  [1, 142, 78],
  [1, 108, 182],
  [1, 396, 47],
  [1, 66,  102],
  [1, 165, 116],
  [1, 8,   106],
  [1, 245, 119],
  [1, 302, 17],
  [1, 96,  38],
  [1, 201, 132],
];

const labels = [
  [0],
  [1],
  [0],
  [0],
  [1],
  [1],
  [1],
  [0],
  [1],
];
```

### Other function definitions for completion

```
function sum(a, b) {
   return a.reduce((acc, val, i) => acc + val * b[i], 0);
}

function sig(z) {
  return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-z));
}
```

### Edit

What the visualization means:

- Random points are created. If the `y` value is below some arbitrary value, that point is set as class 1 (pink). If the `y` value is above the threshold, that point is assigned as class 0 (blue).
- Those points are the training set. The input is the [x, y] coordinates for each point. The class for each point is set as the target labels.
- The algorithm is trained over this set.
- After several iterations of gradient descent, I use the model to classify each pixel in that canvas. If the classification is >= 0.5, I color that pixel yellow. Else, the pixel is colored red. The expectation is that the background will be all yellow on the upper half of the image, meaning that every one of those pixels was classified as type '0'.

Comment: There's some undefined terms in your code: `params` and `lr`.  I also don't see `labels` referenced in your map reduce code.  I just don't think you're providing enough information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I've edited my post to add the `lr` and `params` values. I reference `labels` when calculating `errors` (`score[n] === h(x[n])`)

Comment: describe the figure better. i don't understand the point colors. is it training/test sets? if so, the blue (training?) set only has 5 positive values. which is very unreliable.

Comment: If those are your params, how does the map work?  I would have expected `params` to be an array of 2-tuples based on the signature of the lambda in your map.

Comment: In JavaScript, `['a', 'b', 'c'].map((val, index) => {})`. The first argument passed to the lambda is the value, and the second is its index.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Thanks.  Another one, is `sum` a function you defined?

Comment: Added those misc definitions for completeness

Comment: Thanks for all that.  How many times to do produce a new set of parameters with your map-reduce setup?  Logistic regression takes a few iterations to converge.  I don't see where you are checking for convergence.  If you're wanting to do this in a functional style, the ideas in this paper are very useful: https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been running that update logic for tens of thousand iterations. I calculate the cost after each iteration. I've had the cost (based on those training samples) get below 0.005. But when I plot those new points, I get that pattern in my screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62159/discussion-between-rodrigo-silveira-and-matthew-drury).